# Como colocar a resposta de uma função como parâmetro em outra função?

Tags: javascript, funções, argumento

```js
const soma = function (a,b) {return a+b}

console.log(soma(2,4))

let nun1 = 3

const soma2 = function (soma, nun1) {return soma+nun1}
```

Eu quero pegar o resultado da função soma que é 6 e `somar` com `nun1` que é 3

Como eu posso pegar esse resultado e colocar na segunda função?

Comment: Seria algo como `let nun1 = 3 + soma(2,4);` ?

Comment: Se essa pergunta não for marcada como duplicata, não sei mais o que poderia ser. (não que eu queira que seja marcada, mas acho que é a política e o que vem acontecendo, né ?) E isso nem é culpa do rapaz que perguntou, pois provavelmente ele é novo aqui.

Comment: @ThiaguinhoEmbasamento se você sabe que é duplicata sinale indicando qual é, caso contrário não faça especulações sem embasamento que não ajudam em nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está chamando `soma()` e pegando o resultado para imprimir no console, não guardando em lugar algum, então não pode usar esse valor a não ser que chame a função de novo. Como a função é pura não teria problema a não ser a perda de performance por fazer duas vezes a mesma coisa. Mas esse código nem faz sentido.

Depois não chama `soma2()` em lugar algum.

Para colocar o resultado de uma função como parâmetro de outra função é fazer exatamente o que fez no console, está passando o resultado de `soma()` como parâmetro da função `console.log()`, só que fez com a função errada, você quer fazer isso na `soma2()`.

Aí é só chamar a função passando isso, e mandar imprimir pra ver.

Tenho minhas dúvidas se este código está ensinando alguma coisa ou criando confusão.

Dei uma organizada no código.

```js
const soma = function(a, b) { return a + b; }
let nun1 = 3;
const soma2 = function(soma, nun1) { return soma + nun1 }
console.log(soma2(soma(2, 4), nun1));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Function/ExpressionValueAsParameter.js).

Answer (score 1):

Seja bem-vindo ao SOpt, o que você quer parece ser uma função que faça uma soma a partir de outra soma... Ou seja, basta pegar o resultado da primeira soma e somar com o resultado de outra soma:

```
let nun1 = 3

const soma = function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

soma(nun1, soma(1, 4));
```

Pode fazer isso diversas vezes, exemplo:

```
soma(1, soma(2, soma(3, soma(4, soma(5 + 1)))))
```